# Matlab long format in python

Tags: python, matlab, format, filtering

I need to implement a filter

```
EDA_T = signal.lfilter(b, a, edat);
```

in python with the coefficent:

```
a=np.array([1, -1.994372768943081, 0.99438855043802943], type=np.float64);    
b=np.array([1, 1.9, 1.7])/3e5;
```

it is important to take all decimal number.
With the specified type the array are:

```
 print('a, b: ', a, b)
 a, b:  [ 1.         -1.99437277  0.99438855] [  3.33333333e-06       6.33333333e-06   5.66666667e-06]
```

some number are cutted.
In matlab specifying the format long there is not any problem.
How can I implement this in python?

Comment: You can type a[1] and ensure that the number is right.

Comment: To be sure that the numbers are not cutted you can force python to represent them with the required number of digits`format(x, '.17f')`

Answer (score 2):

That's a representation error, I think.  most machines today use IEEE-754 floats and their use should be interchangeable. SO in your situation is the problem that the representation is truncated or is it that the value has changed. The former will not affect your calculations but the latter will. 
You can look at more decimals by printing it as a string and specifying the amount of decimals. 
For actual, good precision, use the decimal datatype. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html